# Why does my light angle change when the camera moves?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, fragment-shader

Trying to implement point lighting in WebGL, i noticed my light angle changes when i zoom in.

[image]

My vertex shader:

```
uniform mat3 u_rotationMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_transformMatrix;
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_viewCoords;
void main() {
    vec4 tcoords = u_transformMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_viewCoords = tcoords.xyz;
    v_normal = u_rotationMatrix * a_normal;
    gl_Position = tcoords;
}
```

This is for me an unwanted effect. How can i avoid that? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: From what I can see in your image, its not the angle but the intensity? I noticed that the upper plane is as dark as the shrunken model, just that the plane facing you is not lit up as brightly. If the angle had changed, other surfaces of the cube would have brightened / darkened, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not computing [a directional light](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-directional.html). You're computing a point light. A directional light has no position by definition so `light[i].position` makes no sense for a directional light.

Okay, so you're computing a point light. [A point light wants the surface normal dotted with the direction from the surface to the light](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html). But that doesn't appear to be what you're computing. To get the surface to light direction you need to separate out the projection and view matrices from the model/world matrix. Looking at your shader

```
vec4 tcoords = u_transformMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
v_viewCoords = tcoords.xyz;
v_normal = u_rotationMatrix * a_normal;
gl_Position = tcoords;
```

It appears `u_transformMatrix` contains your view and projection matrices. I'd expect the shader to look more like this

```
vec4 worldPosition = u_worldMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
v_viewCoords = worldPosition.xyz;
v_normal = u_rotationMatrix * a_normal;
gl_Position = u_viewProjection * worldPosition;
```

Where `u_worldMatrix` are the result of everything except the view and projection matrices and `u_viewProjection` is the `projection * view` matrix

The reason it was changing when you zoom in is because the view matrix includes the zoom. As such the surface position calculation changes based on where you put the view/camera. By removing that from the calculation that problem should go away.

[You might find these articles helpful](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: GREAT gman, one year has passed since Your answer and I was able only today to understand it fully, after reading it again and again. Sincerely, THX You very much for the time You spend answering *noobs* like me!